# Check Session Cookies over JSONP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, bookmarklet

I have created a bookmark that extracts all images from a page when clicked and sends the img's `src` back to another (remote) server via JSONP.

**Problem:** The remote server has to check for session authentication cookies to ensure that the user sending the JSONP request is logged in before adding the img `src` to the database. I am able to check for the session cookies over JSONP, now if the user is not logged in and I want to allow the user to login at this point, how should I present the login screen?

Also, are there any security risks with checking for session cookies over JSONP?

**Bookmark's jQuery**

*The way I am using `.getJSON` to do JSONP is probably wrong`*

```
$('.thing').on('click', function() {
    var jsonp_url = 'http://mydomain.com/bookmark.js?callback=?';
    var data = {
        type: 'addToLibrary',
        thingImgSrc: 'http://google.com/someimage.jpg';
    };
    $.getJSON(jsonp_url, data, function(resp) {
        // console.log('done');
    });
});
```

**Server response if logged in**

```
addToLibrary(["1"])
```

**Server response if NOT logged in**

```
addToLibrary(["0"])
```

**Callback function**

```
addToLibrary = function(data) {
    if(data == '0') {
        // show login screen
    } else {
        // show OK screen
    }
}
```

**Ideas for User to Login**

1. On receiving `["0"]` indicating an error, popup a window showing login form, login will be done normally since the popup window contains a page from the remote server.
2. On receiving `["0"]` indicating an error, popup an AJAX-style modal box on current page containing the login form, login will be done via JSONP.

Comment: Your server should honour the `callback` parameter that jQuery sends via `$_GET`

Comment: Am I right to say that even though the URL supplied to jQuery is `http://mydomain.com/bookmark.js?callback=?`, the actual URL used by jQuery is `http://mydomain.com/bookmark.js?callback=someVariableSetByjQuery`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not send back an object?

```
addToLibrary( { "result" : ["registereduser@gmail.com"] } );
addToLibrary( { "error" : true, message : "must log in"  } );
```

In your function you check for the error or result and handle it that way. No wondering what Zero is.

```
function addToLibrary(resp) {
    if (resp.error) {
        showLoginPrompt();
    } else {
        addItems(resp.result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, this is much better! I'm wondering if its necessary to define the `addToLibrary()` callback function? I was hoping that `$.getJSON()`'s callback function will be the JSONP's callback function, `addToLibrary()` in this case.I tried with `.getJSON(url,data, function(){ console.log('hey'); });` but it doesnt seem to be called.

Comment: Thanks, I am now using `$.getJSON()` with JSONP the way its intended. Getting a `Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html:` warning when receiving the JSONP response, I guess I'll create another post for this.